# SQL, in multi join with multi condition, i want a value even if other condition is false

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join, where-clause

Here is my query then I explain :

```
SELECT 
    tyds.product_tyd,
    tyds.user_tyd,
    COALESCE(action_tyd, 'NONE') AS action_tyd 
FROM tyds
INNER JOIN users
    ON tyds.user_tyd = users.id_user
INNER JOIN products
    ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product
INNER JOIN companies
    ON products.id_company_product = companies.id_company 
WHERE users.key_user = '14967d378a580cdf020350f4eb626f16'
AND companies.module_key_company = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.'
AND products.cancelled_product >= 0
AND products.code_product = 'app_1'
```

`users.key_user` give me the users.id_user which is also `tyds.user_tyd`.
`companies.module_key_company` give me the `products.company_id_product`

In `products` table I allow an `ID_product` with a `code_product` and `company_id` then I use this `ID_product` to record in my `tyds` table

What I want is to know if this user make records in table `TYDS` for the specified product then get his `id_user` and some other stuff. It works when there is records to found and of course it's not when there is no records or correspondence in the `TYDS` table.

But what I'd like to know is if I can get the `users.id_user` EVEN if there is no records in the `TYDs` table.

So in fact is to get the result of the `users.key_user` even if the three other conditions return FALSE.

I know I asked something similar last week but I can't find out even with the precedent solution.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: There is obviously a communication issue here. Perhaps it would help if you provided some record samples and the results you are wanting.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds more like you want a listing of all users and their corresponding tyds record(s) even if they don't have any related records. I believe this is what you want.

```
SELECT
    users.id_user,
    tyds.product_tyd,
    tyds.user_tyd,
    COALESCE(action_tyd, 'NONE') AS action_tyd 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN tyds
    ON tyds.user_tyd = users.id_user
LEFT JOIN products
    ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product
    AND products.cancelled_product >= 0
    AND products.code_product = 'app_1'
LEFT JOIN companies
    ON products.id_company_product = companies.id_company
    AND companies.module_key_company = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.'
WHERE users.key_user = '14967d378a580cdf020350f4eb626f16'
```

Comment: how is this materially different from my answer?

Comment: @Bohemian You are using inner joins still and also by having the tyds as the first table in the select, you can't get the userids that are missing tyds records

Comment: Sorry to answer so late, i already tried that and, don't know why, the  products.code_product & cancelled_product is not respected so i get every tyds.id_product where products.code_product exists. But as you say, i want the users.id_user even if this user has no records in tyds.

Answer (score 0):

Move those conditions into the join clause's `ON` condition:

```
SELECT 
    tyds.product_tyd,
    tyds.user_tyd,
    COALESCE(action_tyd, 'NONE') AS action_tyd 
FROM tyds
INNER JOIN users
    ON tyds.user_tyd = users.id_user
INNER JOIN products
    ON tyds.product_tyd = products.id_product
    AND products.cancelled_product >= 0 -- moved from where clause to here
    AND products.code_product = 'app_1'-- moved from where clause to here
INNER JOIN companies
    ON products.id_company_product = companies.id_company 
    AND companies.module_key_company = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.' -- moved from where clause to here
WHERE users.key_user = '14967d378a580cdf020350f4eb626f16'
```

Join conditions may contain more than just an "id match". By putting special conditions in the `ON` clause, you restrict the rows returned to just those that join the way you want them, but still getting an empty left join in case they don't (even though there are other rows with the same "id" match).

Comment: See my previous comment and sorry again to answer so late...In this case i get only the tyds lines where tyds.id_product match with with products.code_product so that's good. But, if there is no match for products.code_product, i don't get the users.id_user and i'd love get this id, even if i don't have records for this user in tyds.

Answer (score 0):

I'd link something like that  :

```
SELECT B_user, tyds.product_tyd 
FROM tyds
INNER JOIN products ON tyds.`product_tyd` = products.id_product
AND products.`cancelled_product` >= 0
AND products.code_product = 'app_1'
INNER JOIN companies ON products.`id_company_product` = companies.`id_company`
AND companies.`module_key_company` = 'daL/RqzZcfqc.'
WHERE tyds.`user_tyd` IN 
(SELECT id_user AS B_user FROM users WHERE key_user = '14967d378a580cdf020350f4eb626f16')
```

And get the B_user even if products.code_product is wrong etc...